# After DB login, redirect to another page

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hi I just posted this question [PHP $_SESSION problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818521/php-session-problem/6818652#6818652) - I am able to log my user into the website/database just fine but instead of having it say "you have logged in, $username" - how can I say "you are logged in, $username" and in 3 seconds the page will redirect else where?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could add a meta refresh tag to the header part of the page.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://domain.com/other.php">
```

I would still add a link to go there manually if the page doesn't automatically redirect; Refresh-headers can be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `meta` HTML tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://domain/">
```

Using Javascript:

```
function redirect(url) {
  document.location(url);
}
setTimeout('redirect("http://domain/")',3000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to echo out a meta tag to refresh the page after a delay, to look something like:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://site.com/">
```

Where the 3 is 3 seconds and site.com is the location.

Answer (score 0):

Use sleep(3); followed by header("Location:YourLink");

The number in sleep is how many seconds to wait before continuing and the header command will redirect you wherever you'd like.

Just print out the message to the user before the sleep command and viola.

Comment: That's resources-expensive implementation. The PHP process/thread will hang for 3 additional seconds...

Comment: Also, Sending a header after already displaying a page (xxx, you're now logged in) will result in warnings instead of a redirect

Comment: i get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Comment: is there a way for php to print out "you're in, $username" and then redirect properly?

Comment: No, this cannot be done with php alone, since it generates 1 page and cannot redirect your browser after that. The javascript or html/meta solutions will work.